# Can MySQL output the equivalent of a perl packed integer?

Tags: mysql, perl

I'm trying to pull data from a column in MySQL table directly into a binary file which is a series of packed unsigned integers (4 bytes each) which can be read using the perl unpack function. A silly example of how I might read this data is

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
my $input_file = 'packed_int_test_file_04';
open my $fh, '<:raw', $input_file
  or die "Couldn't open $input_file for binary read: $!";

my $position = 0;
my $four_byte_buffer;
while ( read($fh, $four_byte_buffer, 4) ) {
    my $foo_val  = unpack("I", $four_byte_buffer);
    print("Foo val at position $position is $foo_val \n");
    $position++;
}

# OUTPUT:
# Foo val at position 0 is 1 
# Foo val at position 1 is 2 
# Foo val at position 2 is 3 
# Foo val at position 3 is 4 
# Foo val at position 4 is 5 
# Foo val at position 5 is 6
```

I'm hoping I can generate the data file directly from MySQL with something like the following (but I'm having no luck)

```
select (cast foo_val_integer as binary(4)) 
from bar_table
into outfile 'packed_int_test_file_04'
FIELDS terminated by ''
LINES terminated by '';
```

Is there a way to have MySQL directly output a sequence of 4 byte packed unsigned integers into a binary file which could be read by perl in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format expected by `unpack 'I'` varies from build to build. I believe you are trying to obtain one of the following formats:

- 32-bit big-endian unsigned integer (e.g. `0x12345678` packed as `12 34 56 78`)

  Unpacked in a portable manner using

  ```
  unpack 'L>'
  ```

  Packed using

  ```
  CHAR(
      ( i >> 24 ) & 0xFF,
      ( i >> 16 ) & 0xFF,
      ( i >>  8 ) & 0xFF,
      ( i >>  0 ) & 0xFF
  )
  ```
- 32-bit little-endian unsigned integer (e.g. `0x12345678` packed as `78 56 34 12`)

  Unpacked in a portable manner using

  ```
  unpack 'L<'
  ```

  Packed using

  ```
  CHAR(
      ( i >>  0 ) & 0xFF,
      ( i >>  8 ) & 0xFF,
      ( i >> 16 ) & 0xFF,
      ( i >> 24 ) & 0xFF
  )
  ```

Comment: I don't have MySQL handy to test. Make sure to test with 3,000,000,000

Comment: Thank you (again) @ikegami!  This worked flawlessly! `select CAST(CHAR(
    ( foo_val_integer >>  0 ) & 0xFF,
    ( foo_val_integer >>  8 ) & 0xFF,
    ( foo_val_integer >> 16 ) & 0xFF,
    ( foo_val_integer >> 24 ) & 0xFF
) as binary(4)) from bar_table
into outfile 'packed_int_test_file_04'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '' STARTING BY '' `